# How to contol all spring batch jobs running as scheduled cron jobs by passing a boolean flag to disable or enable the jobs?

Tags: spring-batch

**I have created a job status table where i have a boolean flag based on that i am returning the cron expreesion(active cron or hypen(-) cron) and my scheduler will work. Boolean flag will be updated if you want to enable or disable all spring batch jobs.**

**How can we contol the flag in the application otherwise we will have issues in running the cron expression?**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValueDevice}")
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@getCronValueStorage}")

@Bean
public String getCronValueDevice() {
    JobStatus jobStatus = jobStatusRepository.findByJobName(BatchJobConstants.DEVICE_JOB_NAME);
    if (jobStatus != null && jobStatus.getIsActive()) {
        return jobStatus.getActiveCronExpression();
    } else {
        return "-";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to enable/disable scheduled jobs using a flag, I would keep it simple and make the job launching code conditioned by that flag, something like:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{your.cron.expression}")
public void runJob() {
   boolean enabled = ... // dynamically load the flag as needed
   if (enabled) {
      // run the job
   }
}
```

This does not require to change the cron expression on the fly to enable/disable the schedule. When the flag is false, the job will not be executed at subsequent schedules unless it is reactivated again.

BTW, kubernetes provides a similar feature to [suspend/resume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#suspend)  cron jobs (this can be done on the fly by patching the cron job specification).

Comment: @Beans , I have 2 questions.

So we can integrate Kubernetes cronJob with SpringBatch. So only changes will be removing  scheduled annotation and use k8s cronjob right ?

My 2nd question will be, is kubernetes cronjob following UTC ?

Comment: @Beans there are open issues

Git issue : https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/18579#issuecomment-590065451

Document Update : https://deploy-preview-19269--kubernetes-io-master-staging.netlify.com/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: @Beans Is there any alternative to scheduled or any other way we can achieve it?